# How to reference both a python and environment variable in jupyter bash magic?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I would like to add a bash magic cell with both a environment variable and a python variable, like this:

```
!echo "{1+1}" "$HOME"
```

Expecting it to print:

```
2 /home/ec2-user
```

However, this does not evaluate the python expression, output is:

```
{1+1} /home/ec2-user
```

Removing the environment variable makes the python expression work:

```
!echo "{1+1}" "HOME" 
2 HOME
```

What would be the correct syntax for printing both variables?

Answer (score 1):

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#system-shell-access

The docs has an example with `$$HOME`.

```
In [27]: !echo $HOME
/home/paul
In [28]: !echo $$HOME
/home/paul
In [29]: !echo {i+3} $$HOME
5 /home/paul
```

Looks like `$var` can be parsed as either a substitution from a local variable, or pass it on the shell for its evaluation.  `$$HOME` seems to force the shell use.  But it's not obvious from the documentation how it handles those details.