# Mixing shell variables and python variables in IPython '!command'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker

Trying to figure out whether this behaviour on IPython (v7.12.0, on Amazon SageMaker) is a bug or I'm missing some proper way / documented constraint...

Say I have some Python variables like:

```py
NODE_VER = "v16.14.2"
NODE_DISTRO = "linux-x64"
```

These commands both work fine in a notebook:

```sh
!echo $PATH
# Shows **contents of system path**
!echo /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-{NODE_VER}-{NODE_DISTRO}/bin:
# Shows /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-v16.14.2-linux-x64/bin
```

...But this does not:

```sh
!echo /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-{NODE_VER}-{NODE_DISTRO}/bin:$PATH
# Shows:
# /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-{NODE_VER}-{NODE_DISTRO}/bin:**contents of system path**
```

I've tried a couple of combinations of e.g. using `$NODE_VER` syntax instead (which produces `node--/` instead of `node-{NODE_VER}-{NODE_DISTRO}/`, but seems like any combination using both shell variables (PATH) and Python variables (NODE_VER/NODE_DISTRO) fails.

Can anybody help me understand why and how to work around it?

My end goal, as you might have guessed already, is to actually add this folder to the PATH rather than just echoing it - something like:

```
!export PATH=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-{NODE_VER}-{NODE_DISTRO}/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Looks as though any `$name` that it can't find in its own namespace, disables the substitution.  eg `!echo {NODE_VER} $foo`.  I haven't been able to find the code that performs the `$` and `{}` substitutions - but I expect this behavior will be obvious from that.  I suspect it's intentional, trying to avoid ambiguities.  But I haven't seen it documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How to reference both a python and environment variable in jupyter bash magic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69194172/how-to-reference-both-a-python-and-environment-variable-in-jupyter-bash-magic)

Try

```
!echo /usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-{NODE_VER}-{NODE_DISTRO}/bin:$$PATH
```

`$$PATH` forces it to use the system variable rather than try to find a Python/local one.

Various examples:

```
In [130]: foo = 'foo*.txt'
In [131]: HOME = 'myvar'
In [132]: !echo $foo
foo1.txt foobar0.txt foobar2.txt foobar3.txt foo.txt
In [133]: !echo $foo $HOME
foo1.txt foobar0.txt foobar2.txt foobar3.txt foo.txt myvar
In [134]: !echo $foo $$HOME
foo1.txt foobar0.txt foobar2.txt foobar3.txt foo.txt /home/paul
In [135]: !echo $foo $PWD
/home/paul/mypy
In [136]: !echo $foo $$PWD
foo1.txt foobar0.txt foobar2.txt foobar3.txt foo.txt /home/paul/mypy
In [137]: !echo {foo} $PWD
{foo} /home/paul/mypy
In [138]: !echo {foo} $$PWD
foo1.txt foobar0.txt foobar2.txt foobar3.txt foo.txt /home/paul/mypy
```

Any variable not locally defined forces the behavior you see:

```
In [139]: !echo $abc

In [140]: !echo {foo} $abc
{foo}
```

It may put the substitution in a `try/except` block, and "give up" if there's any `NameError`.

This substitution can occur in most of the magics, not just `!`.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, this works! Just to add for anybody else that comes across the particular use-case mentioned in the question, using this to edit `$PATH` won't actually persist because each `!` command runs in a different subshell so seems to see whatever the original `$PATH` was.