# Expand multiple python variables in one line inside a jupyter-lab notebook

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

I have googled many different sources and cannot determine why the ipython kernel has this behavior on a jupyter notebook, so I'm posting here to figure out why.

I'm using notebooks in order to document commandline analysis, and jupyter notebooks are a very useful format to run commands and have them saved into a pdf.
I want to be able to utilize multiple variable expansions in 1 line of a shell magic command in ipython.

Right now I can accomplish this using multiple %env magic commands like so:

```py
#commented code below for context of commands run in a previous cell:
#ssl_logs are some logs of ssl headers
#ssl_log = f"SOMEDIR/ssl.log"
#!cat {ssl_log} | jq -r '.ja3' | sort | uniq > uniq_ja3.txt
#j3_ua_db = "ja3fingerprint_ua.json" #HTTP user-agent strings associated with each JA3 hash
#j3_hash_db = "ja3fingerprint_hash.json" #before/after hashing

#code I'm running in the specific cell with issues
for j in ja3s:
    %env j {j}
    %env j3_ua_db {j3_ua_db} 
    !echo $j $j3_ua_db
    !grep "$j"  "$j3_ua_db" | jq -cr "{ ja3fp, useragent }"
    break
```

Its output is below:

```sh
env: j=021d3c3f14b88d57a9ce2d946cabe87f
env: j3_ua_db=ja3fingerprint_ua.json
021d3c3f14b88d57a9ce2d946cabe87f ja3fingerprint_ua.json
{"ja3fp":"021d3c3f14b88d57a9ce2d946cabe87f","useragent":"curl"}
{"ja3fp":"021d3c3f14b88d57a9ce2d946cabe87f","useragent":"curl/7.29.0"}
.....
```

However what I want to be able to accomplish is to expand the j and j3_ua_db variables on the grep command and pipe them into jq. When I run the below command, the second variable does not expand, and I think its because ipython won't expand multiple python variables in the same line.

```
for j in ja3s:
    print(j)
    print(j3_ua_db)
    !echo {j} {j3_ua_db}
    !grep {j}  {j3_ua_db} | jq -cr "{ ja3fp, useragent }"
    break
```

OUTPUT:

```
021d3c3f14b88d57a9ce2d946cabe87f
ja3fingerprint_ua.json
021d3c3f14b88d57a9ce2d946cabe87f ja3fingerprint_ua.json
grep: {j3_ua_db}: No such file or directory
```

To be clear, these are all example outputs from simulation data. No internal data is being published here.

### TLDR:

I understand I can just do this in a shell like so:

```
for ja3fp in $( cat uniq_ja3.txt ); do
    grep "$ja3fp" "$j3_ua_db" | jq -cr '{ ja3fp, useragent }'
done
```

But I want to be able to have the same expansion variable functionality in ipython on a jupyter notebook for ease of use, rather than needing to create a %env line for every variable I want to use in multiple lines.

Does anyone know how I can expand **multiple** ipython variables in 1 line of a "!" magic shell command?
Is there some syntax foo I am missing?

**EDIT:
my versions are as follows:

```
python3 --version.  
Python 3.8.5.  

jupyter-lab --version.    
3.3.3.  

ipython --version.    
8.2.0.
```

Comment: The '$` and {}` can expand either local variables, or shell variable, but not both at the same time.  However `$$` can be used for the shall variables.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69194172/how-to-reference-both-a-python-and-environment-variable-in-jupyter-bash-magic/69195980#69195980

Comment: Thank you  I understand it can't do both at the same time, but have you tried doing expansion of two python variables on the same line? 
it isn't working for me, and I want to know if its a syntax issue or an ipython issue

`Edit: Ah I think I see the confusion, the second '{}' is a jq convention to read specific json keys and their values, is it possible ipython is catching these and attempting to expand as well?`

Comment: $, $$, and {} provide various mixes of python and BASH variable substitution.  I thought I'd figured it out in the previous question, but now I'm not so sure.